Android SMS : Prevent from showing or Block or Mute or Dismiss or Hide Actions
Real world problem
there are a ton of ad SMS daily nowadays (at least where I live) different numbers each time (no way to block all of them).
Abstract Solution
having a Service which processes (even a simple word check) the content and decides whether to show SMS nofitication, hide it, mute it, or at least have it lower priority than other important SMS.
Implementation

having an application to run a BroadcastReceiver doing the work

I tried but didn't work

BroadcastReceiver with High priority receiver
Getting all possible permissions on the matter

Ideas

Create default messaging app (work not justified for the purpose)

My Question:
is there any way or idea to do that in android?

On modern Android you'd pretty much have to be the default messaging app.  There's no other way to get between the OS and another app as the default messaging app, which would display the notification. You could try a NotificationListenerService with the idea that instead of blocking the notification, you just immediately cancel it.
